# How do i restrict a User Accessing our services using Rest Client with a valid Session ID?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a Application , where i need to restirct the access to my Webservices if he tries to access the Services with his Session ID ??

I mean once he logouts out of the Application , but he may access our Services based on Session ID using a Rest Client ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add authentication filter checking if the user is logged in before request goes to REST servlet

Comment: In my Authentication Filter i have if(Session==null ) condition , as i said he may access application by entering a Cookie SessionID manually in Rest Client . so is there any way i can prevent this ??

Comment: check for session attribute as well, set upon login, remove upon logout, and the sessionid are generally unique, so if the session is closed with a session id, and if the new request comes with same id it shouldn't create problem if you have filter checking it